# Custom element javascript function not being found

Tags: polymer

I trying to get my head around Polymer. Obviously custom element are key to the whole ShaBang. I did built a few, some are working some I just can't get them to do what I wish.

BTW I am using version 0.5. Why, simply because I am to lazy to change.

Here is my problem.

I want a Paper-Dialog to popup when clicking a link. It works perfectly when the code is directly in the Index.html page. But when I wrappe it a custom element it is unable to find my Javascript event.

I get this error in the console :

"Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleDialog is not defined"

I know it is due to something I don't understand. But I am having a hard time getting the nuts and bolts of Polymer.

Here is the code for what I am trying to do.

```
<polymer-element name="cvirt-reader" attributes="content" >
  <template>   
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleDialog()">Read</a>    

    <div id="HelpDialog">   
      <paper-dialog  id="dlgHelper"  heading="Bottom Dialog" transition="paper-dialog-transition-bottom">
        <a href="#"><IMG src="/cvirtAnimee.gif"></a>
        <paper-button label="Fermer" affirmative autofocus></paper-button>
      </paper-dialog>
    </div>

  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('cvirt-reader', {
      toggleDialog: function(e) {
        this.$.dlgHelper.toggle();
      }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simpler answer

Polymer provides [declarative event mapping](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping) to bind methods of your element to events, using the `on-<event name>` attribute :

```
<a href="#" on-click="{{toggleDialog}}">Read</a>
```

It should work with any event as long as you name your attribute properly ; Polymer will do the rest.

---

## Original answer

I don't think you can set an `onclick` attribute to a function which is not in global scope. Maybe you should try binding a listener with the `ready` function ( `read` would be an `id` for your first `a` element ) :

```
Polymer('cvirt-reader', {
    ready: function () {
        this.$.read.addEventListener('click', this.toggleDialog.bind(this), false);
    },
    toggleDialog: function(e) {
        this.$.dlgHelper.toggle();
    }
});
```

The thing is : when using `onclick="toggleDialog()"` your browser will look for the `toggleDialog` function in the global scope while it really is an attribute of your Polymer element, hence absent from the global scope, causing the `ReferenceError`.

By binding the event listener from inside the `ready` function, everything you need is accessible from your current scope, that is : you can find `toggleDialog` through `this` and add it as an event listener.

> Note the use of `.bind(this)` which will force `this` to reference the Polymer element instead of the event in `toggleDialog` whenever it is caught.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly. But I would love to understand why. My Javascript and Custom Elements knowledge is not where I wish it would be.

Comment: I edited the answer to try and explain the workings of it.

Answer (score 0):

remove the () from `onclick="toggleDialog()"`

Should work if you write it like this: `on-click="toggleDialog"`

Comment: Unfortunatly it did solve the problem. Thnaks for the reply

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: Sorry I missed spelled. I should of wrote : Unfortunatly it did NOT solve the problem....

Comment: Aaa ok. Works in polymer ^1.0

Comment: I just tried this with Polymer 1.0 and it does not work either. I think what you meant was not the native `onclick` but rather `on-click` which is defined and handled by Polymer. Then it would be a better solution indeed than what I suggested.

Comment: Just tried the with a Core-Icon-Button  the on-click="{{toggleDialog}}"  and it worked perfctly. This obviously without using addEventListener.